# Send email with emailcomposer ionic with html and hyperlinks

Tags: typescript, email, ionic-framework

I want to send an email through the component 'emailcomposer' of ionic but at the moment of going to the gmail app it removes the hyperlinks, I would like to know if anyone knows the form so that these are not removed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass HTML body you need to use `isHtml` property in your email compose like below

```
let email = {
  to: 'test@test.com',
  cc: 'cc@rtest.com',
  subject: 'Test mail with HTML body',
  body: '<a href='http://www.google.com'>',
  isHtml: true
};
```

for plain text pass `isHtml: false` and for HTM body pass `isHtml: true`

Hope this will helps!

Comment: it's how I currently have it